# Create an Array from flow type?

Tags: javascript, flowtype, flow-typed

I have a string type like this:

```
export type Event =
  | 'AttachmentAdded'
  | 'AttachmentRemoved'
  | 'FieldUpdate'
  | 'Pause'
  | 'ReferenceAdded'
  | 'StateTransition'
  | 'Unpause';
```

I want to write a condition that checks that a value matches one of these types:

`UpdateEvent.includes(value)`

However I don't want to create a new array called `const UpdateEvent: Event = ["AttachementAdded", ...]`

Is there a way to use the type to check `value` or do I have to duplicate that list of options?

Comment: You could create an enum and generate `type Event` from it and also `UpdateEvent` array

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no way to do what you want in flow. In my codebase I'm doing the duplication.